# Show data in webpage from database

Tags: css, html, jsp, servlets

Suppose, I have updated my database by which I mean that I have inserted a new row of data in my database. Now, I want to edit my web page by that data how can I do this?

Suppose, I have three columns in my database "name", "picture" and "age" now I want to show the latest row of these columns in my HTML page with CSS applied. How can I do this please tell me the codes in terms of JSP  and servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get that value in your servlets from database and then to show it in webpage

You can do two things :

1. Use `request.setAttribute("id",value)`
   In the GET method of servlet,

   `request.setAttribute("name",value)
    request.setAttribute("picture",value)
    request.setAttribute("age",value)`
   And in the jsp, you can get these values as

   `request.getAttribute("name")
    request.getAttribute("picture")
    request.getAttribute("age")`
2. Model

   `model.addAttriute("name",value)`

Use JSTL library and then you get these values in jsp by:

`${name}
 ${picture}
 ${age}`